# two different values in third party JSON API, making Newtonsoft break

Tags: c#, json.net

Hi I'm hoping you can help.

I'm working on converting Stocks data from a third party API to a c# data type, but the problem is, the JSON objects have multiple values.

For example:

```
"sharesShortPriorMonth":{"raw":4680878,"fmt":"4.68M","longFmt":"4,680,878"}
```

the one I want is the fmt value `(4.68M)`, and I'm trying to put it into the C# field `public string sharesShortPriorMonth { get; set; }`

My question is, when I Deserialize from a JSON string, it's expecting something more like `"sharesShortPriorMonth": "4.68M"`

How can I tell Json.NET to take that value?

I've already checked the documentation, the JSONProperty Attribute isn't what i want, because that maps different names. not child values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m curious, why cut the corner this way? Why not just throw it all in a model and then extract it later?

Comment: @Skin that would make sense I guess. I've been away from C# a long time and lost my edge lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would choose the solution of @Serge (but the `sharesShortPriorMonthJo` property should be `private` in my opinion because not necessary from the outside, but rather confusing for the client). If you want to keep your class as clean as possible, then you could use a custom `JsonConverter`, as pointed out by @GuruStron . However, the complexity is just moved in another class, the `JsonConverter` precisely.

---

The simplest (?) `JsonConverter` you could use in your case is:

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    public override string ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var tokens = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        serializer.Populate(reader, tokens);
        
        return (string) tokens["fmt"] ?? throw new JsonReaderException(@"""fmt"" not found in sharesShortPriorMonth");
    }
}
```

The [`Populate`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm) method comes in very handy in this case because we can fill in a dictionary containing all the json attributes, eventually we just need to retrieve the `fmt` property.

The `Stocks` class becomes:

```
public class Stocks
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public string sharesShortPriorMonth { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need either change your `sharesShortPriorMonth` to be of type representing the existing json structure (you can include only needed properties):

```
public SharesShortPriorMonth sharesShortPriorMonth { get; set; }

public class SharesShortPriorMonth
{
    public string fmt { get; set; }
}
```

Or create [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and mark field with corresponding [attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonconverterattributeproperty.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```
public class Stocks
{
    ... another properties

    [JsonProperty("sharesShortPriorMonth")]
    public JObject sharesShortPriorMonthJo { set { sharesShortPriorMonth = (string) value["fmt"]; }}
    [JsonIgnore] 
    public string sharesShortPriorMonth { get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: Good idea, +1, but as I said in my answer I would make the `sharesShortPriorMonthJo` property `private`.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara thank you, I appreciate your interest and fixed my code. I didn't know that json will deserialize to private properties. Live and learn.